# If div has offset from top of page, add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

My main menu adds 'scroll' class to '.mainMenu' when the offset is 25px from the top. This functions fine, but when a user refreshes the page anywhere besides the top of the page, '.scroll' isn't active, so the 'scroll' styles do not apply.

Use case:

- User is on top of page, scrolls down, '.scroll' class is added, turning white background to black.
- User refreshes window when on the middle of the page. The main menu turns back into a white background because scroll isn't added.

I'm looking for something like: 'If mainMenu class is 25px from the very top of the page, then add class scroll to the mainMenu div'.

**Demo:**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 10) {
    $(".mainMenu").addClass("scroll");
  } else {
    $(".mainMenu").removeClass("scroll");
  }
});
```

```css
.gap{
  height: 800px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
ul li{
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.mainMenu{
  transition: background 0.5s; 
}

.mainMenu.scroll {
 background:red;
 z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mainMenu">
  <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="gap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same code you use for the example (use case 1) but with a different event.

Like so:

```
$(function() { // called when page is refreshed

  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 10) {
    $(".mainMenu").addClass("scroll");
  } else {
    $(".mainMenu").removeClass("scroll");
  }
});
```

Comment: Wrapping this into a function for both use cases would cut out duplication

Comment: @charlietfl I agree.